# Match to the nearest command name in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, levenshtein-distance, fuzzywuzzy

I'm trying to create a feature for my discord.py bot that would send command names that are similar to what the user has used as a command when what they have typed in is incorrect. For example, a command called `.slap` exists. But the user enters `.slp` or something similar.

I want the bot to respond with the most similar command(s) which in this case is gonna be `.slap`. I'm a beginner still so I have no idea how to do this. I discovered about a lib called `fuzzywuzzy` and `Levenshtein distance` and I have no idea how to use them for my bot.

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: SO is not a site were we write code for others, please add your current approaches, make an honest attempt to solve the problem, why doesn't it work, any errors/tracebacks, what's the current result, what's the expected result. Take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Well, I'm new at this but I would recommend making different lists of words, and if someone used any word from that list, the bot would have to respond with the correct, command. This will probably work with an `on_message` Event. Try something yourself and if you find any problems Edit your question with your code and tag me so I can see it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, fuzzymatching commands and executing what it *thinks* is right, is not a great thing to add to your bot. It adds a point of failure, which can be pretty frustrating for the user regardless.

However, if you *suggest* a list of possible commands, it would probably work a lot better.

FuzzyWuzzy is a great tool for this.
The documentations for it are extremely helpful, so I really don't think you would have an issue if you actually read them.

My 2 cents for implementing would be (in pythonian pesudocode)

```py
# user had input an invalid command
invalid_command = #userinput

command_list = [#list of your commands]
fuzzy_ratios = []
for command in command_list:
   ratio = fuzzywuzzy.ratio(invalid_command, command)
   fuzzy_ratios.append(ratio)

max_ratio_index = fuzzy_ratios.index(max(fuzzy_ratios))
fuzzy_matched = command_list[max_ratio_index]

return f"did you mean {fuzzy_matched}?"
```

Please try to implement and think why you need to implement it.
You need to actually *try* to implement yourself, or you will never learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
disables = []

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def disable(ctx, command):
    command = client.get_command(command)
    if not f"{command}: {ctx.guild.id}" in disables:
        disables.append(f"{command}: {ctx.guild.id}")
        await ctx.send(f"Disabled **{command}** for this server.")

    else:
        await ctx.send('This command is already disabled')



@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def enable(ctx, command):
    command = client.get_command(command)
    if f"{command}: {ctx.guild.id}\n" in disables:
        await ctx.send(f"Enabled **{command}** for this server.")
    else:
        await ctx.send('This command is already enabled')
```

Now you have to add:

```
if "COMMAND: {ctx.guild.id}" in disables:
    return
```

Between `async def command(ctx)` and your code for this command.

***Warning***: This is really bad way to do this. You can try to save a disables list to a json file. If you need help message me - `Special unit#5323`

Answer (score 0):

Something you could use is aliases. Aliases are shortcuts for commands, here's an example:

```python
@client.command(aliases=["slp","spla","spal","slpa","sap","salp"])
async def slap(ctx):
  #Do whatever slap does
```

to create an alias you add `aliases=[""]` and start adding aliases. Aliases will invoke as commands. If I did `.spla` or whatever alias you added, it will still do what `.slap` does. Hope this helped!